# Fill html-table data with jquery fails Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: jquery, html, angular, typescript

I would like to use `jquery` in `Angular` to create a table based on my data input. I am new to `jquery`, so this might be some dumb thing I forgot, but I cannot say what it is.

Sadly when I execute `ng serve` what happens is nothing, just a blank page.

I got the following code:

**HTML**

```
<body onLoad="createHeaders('#dataTable')">
    <table #dataTable >
    </table>
</body>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MOCKUP } from '../Table';
import * as $ from "jquery";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabular',
  templateUrl: './tabular.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabular.component.css']
})
export class TabularComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  //this is where i want to work in the future, lets just forget about that for the moment
  buildHTMLTableCodeFromTree(selector) {
    //var header = this.createHeaders(selector, MOCKUP.Head);
    $(selector).append("<td>test</td>");
  }

  createHeaders(selector) {
    var headObject = MOCKUP.Head;

    console.log("Er ist in der Methode!");

    var value;
    var colspan;
    var entry = "";

    for (var j = 0; j < headObject.length; j++) {
      entry = entry + "<tr>";
      for (var i = 0; i < headObject[j].length; i++) {
        value = headObject[j][i].value;
        colspan = headObject[j][i].colspan;
        entry = entry + "<th colSpan='" + colspan + "'>" + value + "</th>";
      }
      entry = entry + "</tr>";
    }
    $("dataTable").append(entry);
  }

}
```

The table Head Mockup:

```
export const MOCKUP = {
    "Table": "tab1",
    "Head": [
        [
            {
                "value": "",
                "colspan": 1,
            },
            {
                "value": "2018",
                "colspan": 2
            },
            {
                "value": "2019",
                "colspan": 6
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "value": "",
                "colspan": 1,
            },
            {
                "value": "December",
                "colspan": 2
            },
            {
                "value": "January",
                "colspan": 2
            },
            {
                "value": "February",
                "colspan": 2
            },
            {
                "value": "March",
                "colspan": 2
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "value": "",
                "colspan": 1,
            },
            {
                "value": "Foo",
                "colspan": 1,
            },
            {
                "value": "Boo",
                "colspan": 1,
            },
            {
                "value": "Foo",
                "colspan": 1,
            },
            {
                "value": "Boo",
                "colspan": 1,
            },
            {
                "value": "Foo",
                "colspan": 1,
            },
            {
                "value": "Boo",
                "colspan": 1,
            },
            {
                "value": "Foo",
                "colspan": 1,
            },
            {
                "value": "Boo",
                "colspan": 1,
            }
        ]
    ],
    "Body": [
        [
            {   
                "value": "Total",
                "entryID": -1
            },
            {   
                "value": "10",
                "entryID": 33
            },
            {   
                "value": "24",
                "entryID": 34
            },
            {   
                "value": "66",
                "entryID": 35
            },
            {   
                "value": "0",
                "entryID": 36
            },
            {   
                "value": "23",
                "entryID": 37
            },
            {   
                "value": "24",
                "entryID": 38
            },
            {   
                "value": "21",
                "entryID": 39
            },
            {   
                "value": "10",
                "entryID": 40
            }
        ],
        [
            {   
                "value": "Row1",
                "entryID": -1
            },
            {   
                "value": "10",
                "entryID": 1
            },
            {   
                "value": "12",
                "entryID": 2
            },
            {   
                "value": "0",
                "entryID": 3
            },
            {   
                "value": "0",
                "entryID": 4
            },
            {   
                "value": "0",
                "entryID": 5
            },
            {   
                "value": "0",
                "entryID": 6
            },
            {   
                "value": "0",
                "entryID": 7
            },
            {   
                "value": "0",
                "entryID": 8
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

I wanted it to be a three-rowed header (Year, Month and the last row out of the last values of my `HEAD`-array). I've tried to do it according to

I also tried to do it like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894137/json-data-to-html-table-with-jquery) (so with `$("#dataTable").append(entry);` but that does not change the outcome.

Edit: Indeed there is an error, not in the command prompt where `ng serve` is executed, but in the Chrome-console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: createHeaders is not defined
>       at onload (localhost/:13)

Obviously he did not instantiate the method when executing the HTML-Code.

**Edit:** Why am I trying with jquery? 
*Note: This might not be necessary for the question itself, it is meant as an explanation*

Here's an example of my data:

[image: My data]

and the desired output:

[image: my desired output]

Now the output has to be editable and these edits should be saved in my database (on button click, that's why I saved the entryID in my mockup).

For the communication from Backend->Frontend I thought about the above format of the raw data (that's why I save an entryID):

Comment: why do you want to use jquery to manipulate the DOM in angular?

Comment: @L.A I edited my question and tried to explain what and why I am trying to do it that way. If you have another possibility feel free to tell me :) (I know you shouldn't ask for these things in a question, still I am open for other ideas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something really fast, however, it's best to do without jQuery and reuse as much of the objects you generate as possible.

`<table id="dataTable"></table>`

```
const MOCKUP = [{
  type: 'thead',
  children: [{
    type: 'tr',
    dataset: {id: 1},
    children: [
      {type: 'th', textContent: '', colSpan: 1, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: '2018', colSpan: 2, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: '2019', colSpan: 6, contentEditable: true}
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'tr',
    dataset: {id: 2},
    children: [
      {type: 'th', textContent: '', colSpan: 1, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: 'December', colSpan: 2, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: 'January', colSpan: 2, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: 'February', colSpan: 2, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: 'March', colSpan: 2, contentEditable: true}
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'tr',
    dataset: {id: 3},
    children: [
      {type: 'th', textContent: '', colSpan: 1, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: 'Foo', colSpan: 1, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: 'Boo', colSpan: 1, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: 'Foo', colSpan: 1, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: 'Boo', colSpan: 1, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: 'Foo', colSpan: 1, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: 'Boo', colSpan: 1, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: 'Foo', colSpan: 1, contentEditable: true},
      {type: 'th', textContent: 'Boo', colSpan: 1, contentEditable: true}
    ]
  }]
}];

const cache = {};

function assign(destination, source) {
  for (const key in source) {
    if (source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      const value = source[key];

      if (typeof value === 'object') {
        assign(destination[key], value);
      } else if (null != destination) {
        destination[key] = value;
      }
    }
  }

  return destination;
}

function get(data, pathStr) {
  const path = pathStr.split('.');
  let i = path.length;

  while (--i) {
    data = data[path[i]];
  }

  return data;
}

function disassemble(target) {
  let element;

  while ((element = target.lastElementChild)) {
    target.removeChild(element);
    disassemble(element);

    const type = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
    const c = cache[type] || (cache[type] = []);

    c.push(element);
  }
}

function assemble(target, path, data = []) {
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  data.forEach(({type, children, ...config}, i) => {
    const element = assign(cache[type] && cache[type].pop() || document.createElement(type), config);
    const newPath = `.${i}${path}`;

    element.dataset.path = newPath;
    assemble(element, `.children${newPath}`, children);

    fragment.appendChild(element);
  });

  target.appendChild(fragment);
}

function render(target, data) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    disassemble(target);
    assemble(target, '', data);
  });
}

const table = document.getElementById('dataTable');

table.addEventListener('input', ({target: {dataset, textContent, parentElement}}) => {
  // use this to update local data
  get(MOCKUP, dataset.path).textContent = textContent;

  // easy access to row id (dataset values can only be strings)
  parentElement.dataset.id

  // raw dataset with all types and deep objects intact
  get(MOCKUP, parentElement.dataset.path).dataset.id
});

render(table, MOCKUP);
```

Not as fast as React, but pretty darn close.

Comment: So my thought was that, if I would simply generate a String-object that is formatted like an HTML-table and pass it, this might work, but sadly when an entry is changed I cannot determine which entry it was to update it in my database, or am I missing something? But as i write this comment, I see that my solution is not offering this to me either...

Comment: @Rüdiger I expanded the example a little bit. Now the table can be edited and there's an easy way to get to the id, or any underlying data you might need to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly familiar with Angular, but this piece of code seems strange to me

```
<table #dataTable >
</table>
```

Maybe you meant

```
<table id="dataTable">
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found an error! I updated my description